# Service being called multilple times in Angular

Tags: angularjs, service, ng-controller

I have the following angular service

```
//SERVICES
app.service('userInfo', function($http){
    this.getInfo = function() {

        var BASE_URL = "";
        var requestUrl = BASE_URL + "/getmyproperties";
        return $http({ 
                    'method': 'GET',
                    'url': requestUrl,
                    'headers': { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}
                }).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response.data.d);
                    var userName = response.data.d.DisplayName.split(',');

                    var data = {
                        firstName: userName[1],
                        userImage: response.data.d.PictureUrl,
                        lanID: response.data.d.AccountName
                    };

                    return data;

                }).catch(function(e){
                    console.log("Error: ", e);
                }); 
    }
});
```

Maybe i've misunderstood services as i am just learning Angular, but i want to be able to now use the data.UserName in multiple places in the app, so i thought i could use a service, but the service function is executed twice - which i don't want, how can i take the value and then use it everywhere? Should i use nested controllers?

```
//NAV CONTROLLER
app.controller('navBarController', function($scope, userInfo) {
    userInfo.getInfo().then(function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
    });
});
//END NAV CONTROLLER

//TASK CONTROLLER
app.controller('taskController', function($scope, userInfo) {
    userInfo.getInfo().then(function(data) {
        $scope.test = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getInfo` method is calling a webservice. So everytime you call the method, the webservice is called. A solution would be to store the info into a variable in the `userInfo` service once you got it from the webservice. Then in `getInfo` you first check if the info is allready loaded. If yes, return it. If no, call the webservice. A quick example of how this could look:

```
app.service('userInfo', function($http){
    var userInfo = undefined;
    this.getInfo = function() {
        var BASE_URL = "";
        var requestUrl = BASE_URL + "/getmyproperties";
        if(userInfo) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(userinfo); 
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        return $http({ 
                'method': 'GET',
                'url': requestUrl,
                'headers': { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data.d);
                var userName = response.data.d.DisplayName.split(',');

                userInfo = {
                    firstName: userName[1],
                    userImage: response.data.d.PictureUrl,
                    lanID: response.data.d.AccountName
                };

                return userInfo;

            }).catch(function(e){
                console.log("Error: ", e);
            }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey - this doesn't seem to work, is it because it's resetting userInfo each time it runs?

Comment: I forgot to edit a line. Cache[id] had to be replaced with userInfo. Can you try again?

Comment: Thanks but It still gets called twice :(